# Increasing pixel density for photos to be used in a photobook

Tags: pixel

Due to a camera issue I have ended up with a series of photos that have come out 640 x 480 (at 72 DPI).
I was wondering if there is a good way to increase the pixel size or density in Affinity photo to allow me to get good quality 6" x 4" print sizes (the prints will probably be smaller as they will be in the form of a photobook, but I am using 6" x 4" as a benchmark size).

Appreciate any help on this as the photos are of valuable memories.

Answer (score 2):

It is **never** possible to increase pixel density *and* dimensions while *also* maintaining any sort of image quality.

Software is irrelevant. It's simply not possible.

Answer (score 2):

You can try some sharpness keeping image enlarger program. They guess where is something sharp or thin detail which should stay sharp or thin. Of course non-existing details cannot be excavated up but at least the image will be subjectively sharp and non-pixelated even in 400% size.

The following programs at least work, the results look far better than image resizing (=resampling) in photo editors make.

On1 Resize (not free, but stayed alive tens of years under different brand names, originally = Genuine Fractals)

Smilla Enlarger (freeware)

There are many others with varying quality. Try one.

As an example here's your 200x200 icon resized to 400x400 pixels. In the left On1 Resize is used, In the right is used Photoshop's Bicubic resampling:

[image]

The original 200x200 was far too low resolution for details of human head. No resizing method can invent missing details. Photoshop added blurriness, On1 Resize made it resemble a painting. But things which were possible to present with 200x200 image stay sharp in the On1 version.

Comment: You might add a picture showing what it looks like. So it does not come as a supprise

Comment: Right. An example of too difficult case is added.

Answer (score 0):

The rule of thumb says that images should have a resolution of about *300 PPI* in order to not look pixelated at ordinary reading distance.

PPI means *pixels per inch* so finding the ideal maximal size for your images is a simple calculation:

**Width:** `640 px / 300 PPI ≈ 2.13 inches`

**Height:** `480 px / 300 PPI = 1.6 inches`

Unfortunately that's only about a third of the wanted size. Although it *is* possible to digitally scale the images up, I'm afraid the result will not be ideal. You basically have the choice between *chunky* details or *blurry* details.

Images that are somewhat blurry to begin with (like for example a cloudy sky) might react better to the scaling than images with sharp details.